# React Cognito User Pool - A client attempted to write unauthorized attribute

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

I am banging my head on the wall trying to figure this one out. I have the code below in my react app. I needed to add some way for the user to add a unit/apt number, so I added a custom attribute.

Everything works, but when I include `apt_number: this.state.unitNumber,` I get the error `{code: "NotAuthorizedException", name: "NotAuthorizedException", message: "A client attempted to write unauthorized attribute"}`.

I did go into my settings and make the attributes writable (I tried both with an attribute of `Unit` and `apt number`)

Here is my code:

```
const receivedNewUser = await Auth.signUp({
  username: this.state.email,
  password: this.state.password,
  attributes: {
    phone_number: this.state.phone,
    address: this.state.streetAddress,
    birthdate: this.state.dob,
    locale: this.state.zipCode,
    given_name: this.state.fname,
    family_name: this.state.lname,
    apt_number: this.state.unitNumber,
  },
});
```

What is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `custom:` as a prefix to the attribute name.

Your code should read:

```
const receivedNewUser = await Auth.signUp({
  username: this.state.email,
  password: this.state.password,
  attributes: {
    phone_number: this.state.phone,
    address: this.state.streetAddress,
    birthdate: this.state.dob,
    locale: this.state.zipCode,
    given_name: this.state.fname,
    family_name: this.state.lname,
    'custom:apt_number': this.state.unitNumber,
  },
});
```